# Want a file in android to read/write and need to persist ever after clearing data of app

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences, android-storage

**My Requirement: I need a file to be created in APK itself, It should have access for both reading and writing.**

I tried using asset/res folder, from there i can only read.

I tried sharedPref, able to read and write but if i can clear the data then not able to persist.

**How can i implement this? please suggest me.. Thank you**

Comment: Create your own folder on `getExternalStorageDirectory()` and put your file there.

Comment: `a file to be created in APK itselfl`. That is impossible.

Comment: Okay, Thank you.... any other alternative? @greenapps

Comment: Why do you want yet another? What is wrong with my suggestion?

Comment: `I need a file to be created in APK itself` What are you implying here - add a file then sign the updated package of the app again into the APK and install it again without the user's intervention?

Comment: if i store in externalStorage, then i think it wont be in APK.  am i right? @greenapps

Comment: Sorry @T.M  I didn't get you. My requirement is.. along with the APK i want a file and that should be readable as well as writable.

Comment: Add that file in the APK. Now, check if the file is present in the SDcard. If present, make changes in the external (SD card) file. Otherwise, access the file from the APK and then copy it to SD card and then work on it, again the SD card one.

Comment: If i do so.. I cannot implement my idea. Let me explain you clearly... I need to update the file after some changes, and even if i share the app then this updated file should also include in that APK. If it is in SDcard, then i can't share updated file. @T.M

Comment: Your requirement is not feasible in this way. In such a case, store the file on a server and fetch it whenever the app starts. That's the only way you can accomplish it.

Comment: Okay Thank you @T.M